# Parametrization such that a surface is a differentiable manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The surface is $S=\{(x,y,z) \vert \enspace z=x^2+y^2,x>0,y>0,z<1\},$ which is one quarter of a cylinder with radius and height $<1$.

If we choose $g(z,\phi):\enspace (0,1)\times(0,\pi/2)\to\Bbb{R^3},$ such that $g(\phi,z)=(z\cos\phi,z\sin\phi,z)$, then $g$ is a diffeomorphism from $U=(0,1)\times(0,\pi/2)\to\Bbb{R^3}$, and $g(U)=S$. With such a $g$, do we have that $S$ is a differentiable manifold?

Comment: Are you sure $S$ is a cylinder?

Comment: No, not really.